# how to create a dynamic Message dialog and how to apply over a picture

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

My question is how to crate a message dialog which is look like given picture

[image: Message dialog]

i want to apply this message dialog in bitmap picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.......

Layout msgbox1:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout msgbox2:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/image1" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java code:-

```
private static final int MsgBox1 = 0,MsgBox2 = 1; //Declaration done on top
```

.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
{
     dialog = new Dialog(tagame.this,android.R.style.Theme_Light_Panel);
     switch(id) {
        case MsgBox1:
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.msgbox1);
        break; 
        case MsgBox2:
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.msgbox2);
        break; 

    }
      return dialog;
}
```

For displaying the message1 box you can use...

```
showDialog(MsgBox1);
```

For hide the message box...

```
removeDialog(MsgBox1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a time interval and change your bitmap dynamically.

Edited Detailed Answer:

You may use like this for the imageView.
`imageView.postDelayed (Runnable action, long delayMillis)`

For utilizing the above method,

U have to create a `Runnable` which will handle your `BitMap` value changes. and also implement `Thread.sleep(time)` in `Runnable`.

Generally this method places the `ImageView` after the `delayMillis` value.
So better you have to call this method after initializing immediately the imageView.
And make that `delayMillis` value as ur wish. (In your case, that should be very less).

So that according to that `Thread.sleep(time)` method your bitmap will be changed dynamically.

My First Suggestion: (Set a time `interval` and change your `bitmap` dynamically)

I suggested to set a `Timer` in the `Activity` and based on the `Timer` settings, just provide the `BitMap` values to your `ImageView` to change it dynamically.

Hope you understand and feel usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a custom dialog box.
Step1.Create a style in String file in res

```
<style name="myQuitDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog"> 
   <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>

    </style>
```

Step2. Create the xml file in layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_quit"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/image which u want to show"
 >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Step3. Write code of custom dialog box in src

```
class Custom_Dialog extends Dialog {

        protected Custom_Dialog(Context context, int theme) {
            super(context, theme);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    }
private void show_alert() {
        final Custom_Dialog alertbox = new Custom_Dialog(this, R.style.myQuitDialog);
        Window window = alertbox.getWindow();
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        window.requestFeature(window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        alertbox.show(); 
        alertbox.setCancelable(true);
        alertbox.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);


                 alertbox.dismiss();
            }



    }
```

In this way you can do this.

Comment: Thanks you very much. but i had done what you want to say, I want to create a message box which have functionality to increase size of message box color and apply over image view